# Removing multiple patterns from fasta lines

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I need to change this pattern

```
>UniRef90_Q57KY8 Total protein n=182 Tax=GammaproteobacteriaTaxID=1236 RepID=Q57KY8_SALCH
MKKQLIRTLTASILLMSTSVLAQEAPSRTECIAPAKPGGGFDLTYKLIQVSLLETGAIEKPMRVTYMPGGVGAVAYNAIV
AQRPGEPGTVVAFSGGSLLNLSQGKFGRYGVDDVRWLASVGTDYGMIAVRADSPWKTLKDLMTAMEKDPNSVVIGAGASI
GSQDWMKSALLAQKANVDPHKMRYVAFEGGGEPVTALMGNHVQVVSGDLSEMVPYLGGDKIRVLAVFSENRLPGQLANVP
TAKEQGYDLVWPIIRGFYVGPKVSDADYQWWVDTFKKLQQTDEFKKQRDLRGLFEFDMTGQQLDDYVKKQVTDYREQAKAFGLAK
>UniRef90_G8LKQ2 UPF5341 protein yflP n=80 Tax=Bacteria TaxID=2 RepID=G8LKQ2_ENTCL
MKKQLLSTLAASVLMISASVVQAQDAPSRTECIAPAKPGGGFDLTCKLIQVSMLETGAIAKPMRVTYMPGGVGAVAYNAI
VAQRPAEAGTVVAFSGGSLLNLSQGKFGRYGVDDVRWLATVGTDYGMIAVRADSPWKSLKDLLTAMEKDPNSVVIGAGAS
IGSQDWMKAALLAQQAKVDPHKMRYVAFEGGGEPVTALMGNHVQAVSGDLSEMVPYLNGDKIRVLAVFSENRLPGQLANV
PTAKEQGYDLVWPIIRGFFVGPKVTDAEYQWWVETFNKLQQTEAFKKQRDLRGLFEFNLSGKPLDEYVKKQVNDYREQAKAFGLAK
>UniRef90_E3GB58 Uncharacterized protein n=1 Tax=Enterobacter lignolyticus (strain SCF1) TaxID=701347 RepID=E3GB58_ENTLS
MKKTLLQTVIATALLMSTAAFAVEAPGRTECIAPAKPGGGFDLTCKLIQVSLQETGAIEKPMRVTYMPGGVGAVAYNAIV
AQRPAEAGTVVAFSGGSLLNLSQGKFGRYGVDDVRWLASVGTDYGMIAVRADSPWKSLKDLLTAMEKDPNSVVIGAGASI
GSQDWMKAAKLAQQAKVDPHKMRYVAFEGGGEPVTALMGNHVQAVSGDLSEMVPYLQGDKIRVLAVFAENRLPGQLANVP
TAKEQGYDLVWPIIRGFYLGPKVSDDEYNWWVETFQKLQQTDEFKKQRELRGLFEFNMNGKALDEYVKKQVTDYREQAKSFGLAK
```

To something like

```
>Q57KY8_Gammaproteobacteria
MKKQLIRTLTASILLMSTSVLAQEAPSRTECIAPAKPGGGFDLTYKLIQVSLLETGAIEKPMRVTYMPGGVGAVAYNAIV
AQRPGEPGTVVAFSGGSLLNLSQGKFGRYGVDDVRWLASVGTDYGMIAVRADSPWKTLKDLMTAMEKDPNSVVIGAGASI
GSQDWMKSALLAQKANVDPHKMRYVAFEGGGEPVTALMGNHVQVVSGDLSEMVPYLGGDKIRVLAVFSENRLPGQLANVP
TAKEQGYDLVWPIIRGFYVGPKVSDADYQWWVDTFKKLQQTDEFKKQRDLRGLFEFDMTGQQLDDYVKKQVTDYREQAKAFGLAK
>G8LKQ2_Bacteria
MKKQLLSTLAASVLMISASVVQAQDAPSRTECIAPAKPGGGFDLTCKLIQVSMLETGAIAKPMRVTYMPGGVGAVAYNAI
VAQRPAEAGTVVAFSGGSLLNLSQGKFGRYGVDDVRWLATVGTDYGMIAVRADSPWKSLKDLLTAMEKDPNSVVIGAGAS
IGSQDWMKAALLAQQAKVDPHKMRYVAFEGGGEPVTALMGNHVQAVSGDLSEMVPYLNGDKIRVLAVFSENRLPGQLANV
PTAKEQGYDLVWPIIRGFFVGPKVTDAEYQWWVETFNKLQQTEAFKKQRDLRGLFEFNLSGKPLDEYVKKQVNDYREQAKAFGLAK
>E3GB58_Enterobacter lignolyticus (strain SCF1) 
MKKTLLQTVIATALLMSTAAFAVEAPGRTECIAPAKPGGGFDLTCKLIQVSLQETGAIEKPMRVTYMPGGVGAVAYNAIV
AQRPAEAGTVVAFSGGSLLNLSQGKFGRYGVDDVRWLASVGTDYGMIAVRADSPWKSLKDLLTAMEKDPNSVVIGAGASI
GSQDWMKAAKLAQQAKVDPHKMRYVAFEGGGEPVTALMGNHVQAVSGDLSEMVPYLQGDKIRVLAVFAENRLPGQLANVP
TAKEQGYDLVWPIIRGFYLGPKVSDDEYNWWVETFQKLQQTDEFKKQRELRGLFEFNMNGKALDEYVKKQVTDYREQAKSFGLAK
```

So, getting rid of the database name at the beginning, leaving the code afterwards, followed by an underscore with the name of the Tax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use:

```
$ sed -r '/^>/ s/^>[^_]+_([^ ]+) .* Tax=(.*)TaxID=.*/>\1_\2/' file
>Q57KY8_Gammaproteobacteria
MKKQLIRTLTASILLMSTSVLAQEAPSRTECIAPAKPGGGFDLTYKLIQVSLLETGAIEKPMRVTYMPGGVGAVAYNAIV
AQRPGEPGTVVAFSGGSLLNLSQGKFGRYGVDDVRWLASVGTDYGMIAVRADSPWKTLKDLMTAMEKDPNSVVIGAGASI
GSQDWMKSALLAQKANVDPHKMRYVAFEGGGEPVTALMGNHVQVVSGDLSEMVPYLGGDKIRVLAVFSENRLPGQLANVP
TAKEQGYDLVWPIIRGFYVGPKVSDADYQWWVDTFKKLQQTDEFKKQRDLRGLFEFDMTGQQLDDYVKKQVTDYREQAKAFGLAK
>G8LKQ2_Bacteria 
MKKQLLSTLAASVLMISASVVQAQDAPSRTECIAPAKPGGGFDLTCKLIQVSMLETGAIAKPMRVTYMPGGVGAVAYNAI
VAQRPAEAGTVVAFSGGSLLNLSQGKFGRYGVDDVRWLATVGTDYGMIAVRADSPWKSLKDLLTAMEKDPNSVVIGAGAS
IGSQDWMKAALLAQQAKVDPHKMRYVAFEGGGEPVTALMGNHVQAVSGDLSEMVPYLNGDKIRVLAVFSENRLPGQLANV
PTAKEQGYDLVWPIIRGFFVGPKVTDAEYQWWVETFNKLQQTEAFKKQRDLRGLFEFNLSGKPLDEYVKKQVNDYREQAKAFGLAK
>E3GB58_Enterobacter lignolyticus (strain SCF1) 
MKKTLLQTVIATALLMSTAAFAVEAPGRTECIAPAKPGGGFDLTCKLIQVSLQETGAIEKPMRVTYMPGGVGAVAYNAIV
AQRPAEAGTVVAFSGGSLLNLSQGKFGRYGVDDVRWLASVGTDYGMIAVRADSPWKSLKDLLTAMEKDPNSVVIGAGASI
GSQDWMKAAKLAQQAKVDPHKMRYVAFEGGGEPVTALMGNHVQAVSGDLSEMVPYLQGDKIRVLAVFAENRLPGQLANVP
TAKEQGYDLVWPIIRGFYLGPKVSDDEYNWWVETFQKLQQTDEFKKQRELRGLFEFNMNGKALDEYVKKQVTDYREQAKSFGLAK
```

This relies on the first piece of text you want being the first piece of text after the first underscore (`_`). There might be trailing spaces remaining in the output after the Tax name - your file seems to be inconsistent about whether there is a space before TaxID so it's hard to make this clean. We can remove them if it's important with an extra `s` command to the end -- `s/(.*)\s+/\1` making the complete command:

```
sed -r '/^>/ s/^>[^_]+_([^ ]+) .* Tax=(.*)TaxID=.*/>\1_\2/;s/(.*)\s+/\1/' file
```

#### Notes

- `-r` use ERE
- `/^>/` find lines starting with `>`
- `s/old/new/` on those lines replace `old` with `new`
- `[^_]+` some characters that are not `_`
- `(some chars)` save `some chars` to reference later with `\1` `\2` etc
- `.*` any number of any characters
- `;` separates commands, like in the shell
- `\s+` one or more horizontal whitespace characters

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following perl one-liner:

```
perl -ne 'if($_=~/^>/){($id,$tax)=$_=~/UniRef90_(\S+).*Tax=(.*)TaxID/; print ">",$id,"_",$tax,"\n";}else{print $_;}' input.fa > output.fa
```

This will read from `input.fa`, modify the fasta headers and write to `output.fa`

---

Explanation of the command:

```
perl -ne '                                          #call perl and read the file line-wise
  if($_=~/^>/){                                     #check if the line is a header
    ($id,$tax)=$_=~/UniRef90_(\S+).*Tax=(.*)TaxID/; #extract the ID and the tax string
    print ">",$id,"_",$tax,"\n";}                   #print the new header 
  else{                                             #print the sequence (not a header line)
    print $_;}
' input.fa > output.fa
```